# Outlook share contacts and calendar between client without Exchange Server

Tags: outlook

i need to share contacts and eventually calendars between 10 client in a network without exchange server.

The company network has a domain, and every person has its own user and mailbox (managed by our hosting provider). The company is willing to evaluate low-cost exchange alternatives although the only real need is to share contacts and eventually calendars IMAP accounts working fine for just email.

Is this even possible?

Comment: (....Exchange....) There's a reason they're called "Exchange alternatives". Just get the real thing.

Answer (score 0):

Although there are few third-party products out there which will give what you want but in my experience it's never a permanent solution for any SMB.

You may be interested in various hosted exchange providers out there.
Microsoft has it's own hosted solution: [Office 365](http://www.microsoft.com/office/preview/en/try-more-products)
It now supports public folders. You can get a trial for 30 days and see how it works out.